# How to set a specific image to not be saved in cache

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm building a website which uses PHP GD to create images based on user inputted data.
So for instance I'd have something like this:

```
$image = imagecreate(125, 125);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
imagepng($image, "1.png");
imagedestroy($image);
header("Location: ../index.php");
```

To generate the image 1.png and go back to the index of the site.

On the index I'm simply displaying the code if the file exists with some more simple php

```
<?php if(!file_exists("php/1.png"))
        echo ("<center><h2> No panels added!</h2></center>");
        else
        echo('<img class="p_image" src="php/1.png">');
    ?>
```

The problem I'm running into is that the browser will cache the last 1.png generated, even if the user deleted it and made a new one, and display that.  Is there any way I can stop this from happening without having to rename the file every time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just append a timestamp to the filename. That will essentially make it unique and prevent caching:

```
echo('<img class="p_image" src="php/1.png?'.time().'">');
```

Comment: Not that it's important, but it will get cached; it won't ever be retrieved from cache though.